# Summing partitions of an array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, sum

Suppose I have an array of length 15

```
x = randi([0 5], 1,15);
```

I want to sum every 3 elements of `x` together and put each sum in a new array called `y`, as in the following:

```
y = [y1 y2 y3 y4 y5];
```

Please help me in doing that in Matlab using for loops.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **vectorized approach** that automatically deals with a **possible smaller last chunk**:

```
x = randi([0 5], 1, 15); % example data
N = 3; % chunk size
y = accumarray(ceil((1:numel(x))/N).', x(:));
```

Comment: Can you please show using for loops since this is the requirement

Comment: @Raykh I didn't see that requirement in your question, sorry. Anyway, you have three `for`-loop answers now

Answer (score 0):

you can use `reshape` as follows:

```
y = sum(reshape(x,3,[]))
```

This reshapes your vector `x` to an array 3 by whatever is left, then sum along right dimension...

For the case the # of elements you want to sum doesnt add up to the total length of the vector, you can pad with zeros or NaN at the end to make it work. Here's I chose adding zeros:

```
x = randi([0 5], 1,15);
n = 4   ;  % sum every n elements (which is the number of rows in the reshape)
try
    y = sum(reshape(x, n, []));
catch
    disp('added trailing zeros!')
    x(numel(x) + (n - mod(numel(x), n))) = 0;
    y = sum(reshape(x, n, []));
end
```

(you can do this with an if condition instead, I just like try catch more here)

Comment: can you show me how to implement with for loops please

Comment: Using `try`/`catch` here is pretty bad practise (and unnecessary), you know up front what issue you're trying to handle, so handle it without causing errors! Wouldn't the caught case handle it regardless, making the initial `try` redundant?

Comment: @bla, I used the reshape function to change the array into a matrix of 5X3 then use 2 (nested) for loops to iterate through the matrix and sum.

Comment: @Wolfie , I did end my answer that this can be done with an if condition... it's a matter of preference for this answer, we are not answering a bigger question about code style etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using `for` loops:

```
y = zeros(1,5);
for i = 1:5
    idx = (i-1)*3 + 1:(i-1)*3 + 3;
    y(i) = sum(x(idx));
end
```

Comment: how's that possible? you're gonna have a non positive integer in the loop and Matlab doesn't work that way.

Comment: Why do you think that? If you're refering to `idx`, it always returns integers between 1 and 15 (for this case).
You could rewrite it as `idx = (i-1)*3 + (1:3)`, if that helps you to understand it: in the first iteration, `i = 1` so `idx = (1-1)*3 + (1:3) = 1:3` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Using a reference variable `Target` that is used to indicate the start position of each partition the loop below can be achieved. If you would only like to use only loops an alternative inner loop can be done. This method works almost on the same premise as windowing.

[image: Partioning Loop]

### Method 1: Single For-Loop with Indexing

```
x = randi([0 5], 1,15);
y = zeros(1,length(x)/3);


Index = 1;
for Target = 1: +3: 15
    
Partition = x(Target:Target+2); 
y(1,Index) = sum(Partition);
Index = Index + 1;
end
```

### Method 2: Outer and Inner For-Loops

```
x = randi([0 5], 1,15);
y = zeros(1,length(x)/3);
Partition = zeros(1,3);

Index = 1;
for Target = 1: +3: 15

for Column = 1: +1: 3
Partition(1,Column) = x(1,Target+Column-1); 
end
    
y(1,Index) = sum(Partition);
Index = Index + 1;
end
```